# $timeout doesn't work AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, timeout

Here is my code :

JS:

```
var timer;
$scope.getapi_url = function (n) {
    var url = n;
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
        })
        .then(function successCallback(data) {
            $scope.data = data.data;
            console.log($scope, data);
            timer = $timeout($scope.getapi_url(n), 5000); 
            // passing n if you don't want check n value on starting of function.
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.errorBackend = true;
            console.log(response);
            console.log('error');
        });
};
```

HTML :

```
<button class="btn btn-clear btn-sm" ng-click="getapi_url('myurl') ">Click!</button>
```

After click `getapi_url` my `$timeout` doesn' timeout after 5 seconds, but like every moment. Why?
Thanks for answers in advance!!!

Comment: setTimeout(function () { },0);
You can use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to call AngularJS's timeout wrapper is:

```
$timeout([fn], [delay], [invokeApply], [Pass]);
```

You need to pass a function handler or write anon function directly to fn, instead, you are calling the function.

Use:

```
$timeout($scope.getapi_url, 5000, false, n);
```

To call the function with passing n as a parameter.

Or write anon function directly instead fn:

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.getapi_url(n)
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a subtle mistake here.

Instead of setting up a `$timeout` to call `getapi_url` after 5000ms, you are instead immediatly calling the `getapi_url` method by doing this:

`$scope.getapi_url(n)`

on this line:

`$timeout($scope.getapi_url(n), 5000)`

Effectivly you have just called two functions, the first being; `$scope.getapi_url(n)` and the second being; `$timeout()`.

If you make the following adjustment to you code, your `getapi_url` method will be invoked once the `$timeout` period of 5000ms has lapsed:

```
function successCallback(data) {

    $scope.data = data.data;
    console.log($scope, data);

   // This is calling getapi_url immediately, at the point of creating your timeout
   // timer = $timeout($scope.getapi_url(n), 5000); 

   // You should do this instead
   timer = $timeout(function() {
        $scope.getapi_url(n);
   }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
timer = $timeout(function(){ $scope.getapi_url(n)}, 5000);
```